# Complication family for Nike Hybrid watchface (ring text)

Tags: swift, watchos, apple-watch-complication

i want to build a complication for the nike hybrid watchface on the newer apple watch nike.
This watchface has a complication in the middle ring.
You can definetely make your own complication for this type, because i can choose a complication for the google maps and xiaomi apps.

Unfortunately i don't find any complication family for this complication. So far i tried CLKComplicationTemplateGraphicBezelCircularText and CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianLargeFlat.
Both don't show my complication in said space.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My bad! The complication family is indeed CLKComplicationTemplateUtilitarianLargeFlat. I was missing the descriptor in getComplicationDescriptors().